# this.template.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying to loop over all the expandable steps in [this](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/setup-assistant/#Hub-with-Expandable-Steps) example but when I run the code below I get this error:

> this.template.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class AddProductWizard extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback(){
        this.template.querySelectorAll('.slds-setup-assistant').addEventListener('click',this.handleClick);
    }

    handleClick(e){
        console.log("Clicked " + this.id);
    }    
}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `querySelectorAll()` method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector, as a static NodeList object.

This means that you need to access the individual elements using array notation:

```
var setupAssisstants = this.template.querySelectorAll('.slds-setup-assistant')
setupAssisstants[0].addEventListener('click',this.handleClick);
```

It's probably a good idea to add some null/undefined checks before adding the event listener.